# How can I use ranges max to find the closest point to another given point?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

So I've created a structure called `point` that will consist of two integers. Then, created a function called `closest()` that's  going  to  take  an `std::vector` containing points, and  another `point`,  as  a separate argument. It should return a point from that group (one of the points from the passed vector) that is closest to the one passed as the second argument. For calculating distance between two given points I have to use Euclidean distance. How I can rewrite this code using `std::ranges::max`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cfloat>
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

double closest(const std::vector<Point>& points, Point originPoint);

double range(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points = std::vector<Point>(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Point point = {i, j};
            points.push_back(point);
        }
    }

    std::cout << closest(points, {-1, -1}) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

double closest(const std::vector<Point>& points, Point originPoint)
{
    double min = DBL_MAX;

    if (points.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (auto point: points)
    {
        double current_range = range(originPoint.x, originPoint.y, point.x, point.y);

        min = current_range < min ? current_range : min;
    }

    return min;
}

double range(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I'd suggest calling the `range` function `distance` instead, and have it take 2 `Point`s, rather than 4 `int`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cfloat>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Point &p) {
    out << "Point{" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "}";
    return out;
}

Point closest(const std::vector<Point>& points, Point originPoint);

double range(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points = std::vector<Point>(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Point point = {i, j};
            points.push_back(point);
        }
    }

    std::cout << closest(points, {-1, -1}) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Point closest(const std::vector<Point>& points, Point originPoint) {
    return std::ranges::max(points,
        std::ranges::less(),
        [originPoint](Point p) {
            return range(originPoint.x, originPoint.y, p.x, p.y);});
}

double range(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
}
```

Comment: "Functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded"

Comment: @UlanDuishenaliev And that is relevant when fixing his attempts for the `clostest` function how?

Comment: I've tried to delete double closest, but then it shows me new error and I've no idea what to do